# phpmyadmin 5.1.3 - impossible to create/edit anything

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a server based on Debian 11.3, using apache 2.4.53, php8.0, mariaDB10-5.15, PhpMyAdmin 5.1.3, Nextcloud 23.0.3

This server is up and running fine, except for PhpMyAdmin.

I can access the GUI, i can log in, I can add 2FA for existing users,

So far so good, **BUT:**

*(Of course, I am logged with an user having all privileges and all grants on .)*

My problem: trying to crteate/edit anything ( bases, tables, row, data ) is impossible.

Thanks

During edit, no error code, just loading

Example: trying to insert a value, click on GO, the "loading" sign is on... forever, nothing happen.

Table structure seem fine, with first raw called ID, been primary... so it is not link to the

If there are no unique columns or primary keys, functions such as edit, copy, delete, etc. are prohibited for performance and security reasons

Comment: You may want to include a stack trace or system logs to help. This question is also not exactly common on this community as it's more of a collective review not necessarily a broad how do i get a system to work type area

Comment: Hi jon, unfortunately, i have no log or trace, as the GUI simply hangs, just having screenshoots:   https://n2.rkn.ovh/index.php/s/mnEim9RRoyQQtDz